# session flash and validation errors not work in new route file

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

laravel 5.8 
hi
I've added a new route file in routes directory with this name 'admin.php' 
session flash and errors validation don't work in this route file 
but in web.php session flash and errors of validation works well

this is map method in RouteServiceProvider

```
 public function map()
    {
        $this->mapApiRoutes();

        $this->mapWebRoutes();

        $this->mapAdminRoutes();
    }
```

mapAdminRoutes method

```
   protected function mapAdminRoutes()
    {
        Route::prefix('admin')->middleware(['auth','admin'])
            ->namespace($this->namespace."\Admin")
            ->group(base_path('routes/admin.php'));
    }
```

I don't use any middleware in admin.php routes

I Tried 
deleting `->middleware(['auth','admin'])` in mapApiRoutes method

note:session flash and error validations of routes of admin.php work well in web.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply session middlewares for the new routes file in `app/Http/Kernel.php`

`App\Http\Kernel`

```php
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'admin' => [
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    ],
];
```

> I stripped out other middlewares and `web` and `api` for brevety, KEEP THEM

You can see that the `web` group applies the `StartSession` and the `ShareErrorsFromSession` middlewares, and so you must do that manually for the new routes file too

Hope this helps